# Trying to Use a Computed/Generated Field as Link to Another Table

Tags: t-sql

I need to pull one table as left join or outer apply using a field that is generated.  The right table has a field, pnlNumber, which is a concat of 2 different fields in the left table.  So, I first have to put together the pnlNumber using the DeptCode and EmpNumber from the left table.  This field is then used to link to the Personnel table  I have tried using a cte with a left join and also using an outer apply.  In both cases the generated pnlNumber is an invalid field.  Any suggestions for another way to go?

The relevant table info looks as such:

```
Employee Table (Left Table): 
    DeptCode int,
    EmpNumber int

Personnel Table (Right Table):
    pnlNumber nvarchar(7),
    Area nvarchar(25)
```

Here is the sql for both attempts:

```
with cte as(
    select right( '00' + rtrim( convert(char(2), emp.DeptCode) ), 2 ) +
           right( '00000' + rtrim( convert(char(5), emp.EmpNumber) ), 5 ) as pnlNumber
    from RDB..Employees as emp
)
select cte.pnlNumber, pnl.Area
from cte
left join
THRDB..Personnel as pnl
on cte.pnlNumber = pnl.pnlNumber





select  RIGHT(('00' + RTRIM(CONVERT(CHAR(2), emp.DeptCode))), 2)
        + RIGHT(('00000' + RTRIM(CONVERT(CHAR(5), emp.EmpNumber))), 5) AS pnlNumber,
        comb.Area
from RDB..Employees as emp
outer apply(
    select pnlNumber, Area
    from THRDB..Personnel
) as comb
where comb.pnlNumber = emp.pnlNumber
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears you're not actually selecting columns from the `Employees` table therefore you should be able to select from `Personnel` with an *exists* criteria:

```
select pnlNumber, Area
from THRDB.dbo.Personnel p
where exists (
  select * from RDB.dbo.Employees e
  where Right(('00' + RTrim(Convert(char(2), emp.DeptCode))), 2)
       + Right(('00000' + RTrim(Convert(char(5), emp.EmpNumber))), 5)
       = p.pnlNumber
);
```

If you *did* want to select columns from both tables you could use `apply(values(<your computed column>))` to materialise the `Employees.pnlNumber`, such as:

```
select e.<columns>, p.<columns>
from RDB.dbo.Employees e
cross apply(
  values(Right(('00' + RTrim(Convert(char(2), e.DeptCode))), 2) 
         + Right(('00000' + RTrim(Convert(char(5), e.EmpNumber))), 5))
)v(pnlNumber)
left join THRDB.dbo.Personnel p on p.pnlNumber = v.pnlNumber;
```

Comment: I apologize.  I kind of wrecked this question by whitewashing things to a generic test case.  I will actually have several other fields to pull from the Employees table.  

That said, your answer definitely gave me some new directions to look at.  Thank you.  I managed to expose the value by using a cte, a select, and an outer apply.  Unfortunately, this increased my return by 3.8x.  Cross apply and outer apply both return the same 3.8x

Comment: Perhaps you oversimplified your query to the point where cruicial intentions are lost. Using apply with values table constructor would not normally have such a detrimantal effect but I have no idea what you are actually doing.

Comment: @Astennu I've added an actual example of using apply with values, does that help you out at all?

Comment: All of this helps, and I deeply appreciate your help (and everyone else's help on other questions).  This is a great place.